# How can I manage and disconnect specific active Internet connections?

Tags: windows-7, networking

On Windows 7, I need to manage my Internet connections.

Let's say I'm playing an online game. Machines connect to me. My machine connects to them. I would like to see the IP addresses involved in this – also, I would like to be able to disconnect selected connections.

I know [cFosSpeed](http://www.cfos.de/en/cfosspeed/cfosspeed.htm) shows connections, but does it disconnect them?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I really don't get it, I am not even sure if you know what you want yourself. Also it would help if you'd mention your OS. Please be more detailed in your question otherwise it is likely to be closed as it is too vague.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7. Sorry for this. But I still can't figure out why this is closed. I just want an app or a way which shows IP adresses connected to me and lets me disconnect them or doing any network based processes to them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I've reopened the question. Please note that product recommendations are considered off topic, thus it's always easier to just ask for what you want and not a specific "app to do it" – you'll get answers regardless. Next time just [edit] in any additional information you can provide us.

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok sometimes SuperUser (or StackExchange sites in general) is a bit rough for first time users, thats due to relatively high standards compared to other Q&A sites on the web.

Answer (score 0):

`TCPView`, which is a part of Sysinternals suite, should do the trick. 
You can read the spec and download it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: I've installed Windows 8. With Windows 7 and cFosSpeed, I could see connections with IP addresses. Now with TCPView and Windows 8, It just shows me the app (with packets etc...) which is Opera Browser. No IP address... Am I missing something?

Comment: not sure about w8, normally you can choose to resolve names or not from menu (or keyb shortcut `ctrl-R`).